# Avoiding Collisions With Self in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm firing lasers from a cannon in a 2d space game in unity using the following method:

```
[Command]
private void CmdFire()
{
    GameObject laser = (GameObject)Instantiate(LaserPrefab, leftShot ? leftCannon.position : rightCannon.position, leftShot ? leftCannon.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) : rightCannon.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90));
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(laser.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), transform.FindChild("PlayerShip").GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(laser.GetComponent<Collider2D>(), transform.FindChild("PlayerShip").FindChild(leftShot?"LeftCannon":"RightCannon").GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    laser.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 0;
    laser.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = laser.transform.right * 10;
    NetworkServer.Spawn(laser);
    leftShot = !leftShot;
    Destroy(laser, 2f);
}
```

The important bit being the `Physics2D.IgnoreCollision()` sections that are designed to stop them shooting themselves. This works exactly as expected on the host (you can shoot the other ships but not yourself) but the lasers constantly hit their own ship on the client machines.

As you can see here:

[image: Demo]

This is my first attempt at making a multiplayer game in Unity so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's the client code?  Anyway, the easiest thing to do is to ensure the laser originates _just ahead_ of the laser turret so as not to collide with it in any case

Comment: I might've missed something but don't clients run the same as the server except in the case of Commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you could add a tag to your player, like "Player" and check in `OnCollisionEnter2D` whether or not the bullet is colliding with the player that way:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D coll) {
    // If the tag of the thing we collide with is "Player"...
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        Debug.Log("Player hit!");

    // Ignore the collision with the player.
    Physics2D.IgnoreCollision(player.collider, collider);
}
```

Another way is to give the player a different layer to the bullets and ignore collisions between the player and bullet layers:

```
Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(PlayerLayer, BulletLayer, true);
```

Or go to Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D and choose which layers collide with each other there:
[image: Collision Matrix]

You would probably want to add your own custom layers for Player and Bullets.

Comment: Surely the bullets wouldn't then collide with any other players?

Comment: Oh, I misread, you want to be able to shoot other players. In that case you could give each player a tag unique to itself and ignore their own tags. Now Austin's answer makes more sense than this one since the ID is unique to each object.

Comment: Ahh right okay, like a GUID? I've gone with MickyDs suggestion for now but you guys have both given pretty useful answers, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the OnCollisionEnter2D of the laser, check if the gameObject is the "yourself"
by comparing the ID

`If( collider.gameObject.GetInstanceID() != yourself.gameObject.GetInstanceID() )`

Comment: Will that stop it hitting subobjects too?

Answer (score -1):

go to Edit > Project Settings > Physics 2D and choose which layers collide with each other there:

[image]

Comment: Why would you copy a pre-existing answer?